# How to compile and link .cpp file in Rust?

Tags: c++, rust, linker, ffi, rust-cargo

How do I compile and link a .cpp file in a Rust project?

Suppose that I have a Rust project and I want to call some `extern "C"` functions, from Rust, that are C++ or C functions.

What should be the simplest way of doing it?

Answer (score 6):

For complicated projects, [cmake crate](https://crates.io/crates/cmake) should be useful, but for small projects, just use Rust's build.rs.

In the `build.rs`, do

```
fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .cpp(true)
        .file("src/my_lib.cpp")
        .compile("lib_my_lib.a");
}
```

which should be placed in the root of the project. Then simply run `cargo build`. For `C` files, take off the `.cpp(true)`